# Hiding embedded tweet until Twitter JS loaded

Tags: twitter, format, embed, hide

I'm trying out the new embed Tweet feature https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets and it renders horribly until presumably the js file is run and it styles the Tweet. I'd like to hide the Tweet until it is properly styled. Is this possible? I've moved the js file towards the top of the head section to try to get it loaded early.

The example is at http://www.photogenix.biz - I've put it inside a container div with width and min-height set to try to control the horribleness :) Any advice at all? If code is involved I would really need it as specific as possible.

Comment: Thank you @Chamilyan it does for me too but just looks a mess until it is formatted and is in a prime spot on the site. I've tested across all modern versions of browsers and is same issue - maybe my connection speed is slower than yours (I use incognito mode to ensure fully fresh reload).

Comment: that's possible. Though I'm on a slow broadband connection and also don't have your site cached. i really didn't see anything amiss. Maybe someone who is seeing the issue would be able to help better. GL.

Comment: To help those who will land on this question, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681919/embedded-tweets-completion-event) might help.