# Embedded tweets completion event?

Tags: twitter, jquery-masonry

Using Twitter's embed code for single tweets causes a script called widget.js to be loaded. This script is responsible for dynamically generating the HTML of the tweet.

Is there an event triggered by widget.js when the rendering of an embedded tweet is complete? How can my code find out that rendering is complete?

I need this because I am trying to use jQuery Masonry to layout a set of tweets. Masonry fixes the container height for each tweet *before* the tweets are fully rendered, causing overlap. I'd like to be notified that all tweets are fully rendered in order to refresh the Masonry layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a jQuery "watch" plugin (e.g. https://github.com/darcyclarke/jQuery-Watch-Plugin) to watch for DOM changes on the container div.

Comment: Specifically, I watch for the 'data-twttr-id' attribute that twitter adds to the container div.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the [uncompressed code here](http://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js) searching for "render" yields this interesting conditional

```
    if (this._rendered) {
        var anchor = this.byClass('twtr-join-conv', 'a');
        anchor.href = 'http://twitter.com/' + this._getWidgetPath();
    }
```

and somewhat lower in the code is

```
    this._rendered = true;
    // call the ready handler
    this._ready();
    return this;
```

you might be able to explore...

Comment: Thanks but this snippet was used in the Twitter stream widget, not the Tweet embed.